# Two way binding in Next.JS form

Tags: next.js, components

I have a page with multiple components, and on each component form. On showing component on page I´m passing object to that component (props) and binding it to form, and that works fine.
The problem is when I hide component, data that was entered in form is not in the object. I can´t use submit on form because the button for saving data and changing component is on the page, not on component.
How to submit data from form to object on component (on component changing).

I tried to add submit button on form and then data is submited to object, but that scenario is not possible in my case.

Here is how page code look´s like:

```
return (
    <div>
      <div className={`${index === 0 ? 'mb-10 w-full' : 'hidden'}`}>
        <ComponentOne test={test1}/>
      </div>

      <div className={`${index === 1 ? 'mb-10 w-full' : 'hidden'}`}>
        <ComponentTwo test={test2}/>
      </div>
      
      <button onClick={back} className='m-5'>Previous</button>
      <button onClick={next} className='m-5'>Next</button>
    </div>
  )
```

In components I have a form, and object is binded to that form, but without submit button.

Answer (score 0):

it should be because when you hide the component it following the component life cycle, so he is no longer present in the virtual dom and it will be unmounted, you can check it by writing a console log in an anonymous function at the end of the useEffect hook.

Next is a framework built on top of react on the frontend side and react does not have two way data binding like angular, there are however different ways to save the data and make it available to the parent component or in any case more components in general, I think its good to use useContext for this situation or in a simpler way pass test and setTest as props to the forms as state variables so that the test value is saved when the input is changed I suppose, so you should have the variable updated in the parent component  when the form is submitted even if the forms are hidden